# BIOS Interrupt 0x10 Does Not Print/Display Anything

Tags: assembly, interrupt, qemu, bootloader, fasm

I am trying to print a string using assembly (FASM) and the BIOS interrupt 0x10.
I declared the string, and used a loop to load the string character by character into memory and print the individual characters via `int 0x10`.

I tested my code in QEMU, but the string never got printed out. I tried to print only a single character and that did not work.

Here is the bootloader code `boot.asm`:

```
format COFF 
public _start

_start:

    org 0x7C00
    mov si, msg
    mov ah, 0x0E     ; Set interrupt code

    print:
        lodsb        ; Load the character
        or al, al    ; Check for 0x0
        jz hang
        int 0x10     ; Call interrupt
        jmp print


hang:
    jmp hang         ; Infinite loop

msg db 'This is a test sentence.', 0x0
times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
db 0xAA
db 0x55
```

Here is `linker.ld`:

```
ENTRY(_start);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text);
        _text_end = .;
    }
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }

    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss :
    {
        *(COMMON)
        *(.bss)
    }

}
```

The code was built via the following commands:

```
fasm boot.asm boot.o
i686-elf-gcc -T linker.ld -o test.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib boot.o
```

and was run via this command: `qemu-system-i386 -L "%QEMU%" -machine type=pc-i440fx-3.1 -kernel test.bin`

What is certainly odd is that if I remove the `format COFF` from `boot.asm`, assemble it with: `fasm boot.asm boot.bin` , turn it it to a .img file via `copy /b boot.bin boot.img`, and use QEMU to test it, it actually prints the string.

Any thoughts on why nothing gets printed in the original code but it does with the modified one? Have I done/understood/overlook something?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to go through the COFF object and linker?

Comment: I will soon also be using C code with the bootloader so I am using the COFF format.

Comment: If you use COFF and link your boot loader, `org 0x7C00` is wrong and should be omitted.  This is because the linker script sets up the base address.

Comment: Omitting `org 0x7C00` makes FASM give the following error: `fasm boot.asm boot.o
boot.asm [6]: 
    mov si, msg 
processed: mov si,msg 
error: invalid use of symbol.
`

Comment: @RinasSam I am not familiar with COFF (and it is strange that you use COFF in conjunction with the GNU toolchain).  It is plausible that COFF, being a 32 bit format, does not support 16 bit relocations.

Comment: The `test.bin` you're creating is some sort of ELF or COFF executable, not a flat binary.  As a telltale sign, I bet you can notice that it's more than 512 bytes.  `fasm` without `format COFF` apparently knows to create flat binaries, but `ld` doesn't.  When you boot it you're probably trying to execute the header instead of your actual code.

Comment: @fuz You are right. [COFF does not support 16 bit relocations](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=42704). Thank you.

Comment: @RinasSam You can always use ELF for the GNU toolchain.  Also make sure to create a raw binary file from the ELF output of `ld` (e.g. using `objcopy`) so you don't have any headers in it.

Comment: @RinasSam You might like to create your boot sector by simplyfing the example at 
 https://euroassembler.eu/probin/boot16.htm which is much easier to build than FASM & ld.